# Rails has_many through across workspaces ignores class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, has-many

I'm working with a simple has_many through relationship between 2 models.

The Achievement model describes an achievement that can be conquered by a Professional::Company, through the ConqueredAchievement table, that holds when it was conquered.

As I am working acrosss namespaces, I know I have to supply the full class name when creating the relationship, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, as it throws the exact same error with or without the value passed to class_name.

Here's the code for the models:

```
class Achievement < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :conquered_achievements
end

class Professional::Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conquered_achievements
  has_many :achievements, through: :conquered_achievements
end

class ConqueredAchievement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :achievement
  belongs_to :professional_company, class_name: 'Professional::Company'
end
```

When I try to create an association, by using:

```
c.conquered_achievements.create!(achievement: a)
```

I get the error (same error with and without the class_name on the ConqueredAchievement model):

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'company_id' for ConqueredAchievement.)
```

On the generated table, the row is actually named professional_company_id.

I've seen a lot of complaints about has_many through not working properly across namespaces. Am I doing something wrong, or is this actually a bug?

Comment: Have you tried using `belongs_to :professional_company, class_name: 'Professional::Company', foreign_key: :professional_company_id` and/or `has_many :conquered_achievements, as: :professional_company`?

Comment: Even using the foreign_key: :professional_company_id, it still throws exactly the same error.
Just tried as: :professional_company, and the error changes to:

ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'professional_company_type' for ConqueredAchievement.)

Comment: Apologies, moving too fast. `as:` is for a polymorphic association. You might also try: `has_many :conquered_achievements, foreign_key: :professional_company_id`.

Comment: That did the trick. No clue how I'd figure that out, as the docs seem to only talk about class_name.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Super. Added as an answer. Please feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers. (Also, I added a reference to the relevant section of the docs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
class Professional::Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conquered_achievements, foreign_key: :professional_company_id
  has_many :achievements, through: :conquered_achievements
end
```

The clue is in the error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'company_id' for ConqueredAchievement.)
```

The association is trying to use an attribute named `company_id` on `ConqueredAchievement` to find the `Professional::Company`. But, as you say, that attribute doesn't exist.

Instead of letting rails try to infer the foreign key, you can stipulate the foreign key using the `foreign_key:` option as described in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference), section 4.3.2.6.